# How can I loop through divs and add a class if all children are set to display:none?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to hide a paragraph tag if all the children of its sibling are set to display none.

Here is an example of some of my code (the rest is just more of the same divs):

```js
var templateheading = $('.js-template-heading');
var templategrid = templateheading.next();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="c-templates-wrapper">
  <p class="js-template-heading">These themes are available on <strong>Starter</strong> website packages.</p>
  <div class="c-templates-grid">
    <div class="js-template">Starter 1</div>
    <div class="js-template">Starter 2</div>
    <div class="js-template">Starter 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c-templates-wrapper">
  <p class="js-template-heading">These themes are available on <strong>Pro</strong> website packages.</p>
  <div class="c-templates-grid">
    <div class="js-template">Pro 1</div>
    <div class="js-template">Pro 2</div>
    <div class="js-template">Pro 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just to store the paragraphs and the grids in their own variables.

So basically, I need to loop through every templategrid and if ALL of the children within it are set to display none via a style tag (done with a filter), add a class to either c-templates-wrapper or js-template-heading (I basically just want to hide the corresponding paragraph it if theres nothing to show within the grid below it).

I hope that makes sense and I hope someone can help.

Comment: I do not know whether I get your question or not, but wouldn`t it be better to check it with a boolean which you can set to true if filter is pressed and then hide the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$('.c-templates-wrapper p.js-template-heading').filter(function() {
  return $(this).next().find(".js-template:visible").length == 0
}).hide()
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".c-templates-wrapper:first .js-template").hide()

$('.c-templates-wrapper p.js-template-heading').filter(function() {
  return $(this).next().find(".js-template:visible").length == 0
}).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c-templates-wrapper">
  <p class="js-template-heading">These themes are available on <strong>Starter</strong> website packages.</p>
  <div class="c-templates-grid">
    <div class="js-template">Starter 1</div>
    <div class="js-template">Starter 2</div>
    <div class="js-template">Starter 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="c-templates-wrapper">
  <p class="js-template-heading">These themes are available on <strong>Pro</strong> website packages.</p>
  <div class="c-templates-grid">
    <div class="js-template">Pro 1</div>
    <div class="js-template">Pro 2</div>
    <div class="js-template">Pro 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. I have added it in and you can see it at the following: http://preview.aiir.com/templates/templates.html

I wanted to add it in here so you can see it in context with the filters. Do you know if there is a way to add additional code so that it reappears when you un tick the filter at all? For example, if you tick 'multiple locations' you will see the starter title disappear but it won't reappear when you untick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have coded. But if I ***hide*** the paragraph, on ***display:none of sibling's children*** then you cannot see anything because everything will get hidden. So, I modified the code. But you can easily set it according to your need.

I just use CSS to **display:none** to **children**. And then on display:none, I change the **background-color** of Paragraph to red.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var paragraph = $(".js-template-heading");
    if(paragraph.siblings().children().css("display")=="none"){
        paragraph.css("background-color","red");
    }
});
```

```css
.js-template{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="c-templates-wrapper">
        <p class="js-template-heading">These themes are available on <strong>Starter</strong> website packages.</p>
        <div class="c-templates-grid">
            <div class="js-template">Starter 1</div>
            <div class="js-template">Starter 2</div>
            <div class="js-template">Starter 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason this code seems to hide the paragraphs no matter what. I've changed it slightly to

`var paragraph = $('.js-template-heading');
        if(paragraph.siblings().children().css('display')==='none'){
            paragraph.css('display','none');
        } else {
            paragraph.css('display','block');
        }`

but see result at http://preview.aiir.com/templates/templates.html. When you click a filter it still hides them all, even though they should show as each group has at least one item that isn't hidden